# WordPress auto-check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have installed a custom plugin in WordPress which render a check box for a subscription to a newsletter service (mailchimp).

The plugin does not allow to "default the check box"... as you can see below, none of the newsletter option is selected by default (please look here: http://italiancrypto.it/register/ )

[Default not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TNRe.png)

I need help on:

1) understanding where to write custom code (I can onnly use the GUI, not modifying the ore)

2) that function I need to call for:

- default the daily newsletter check box
  [Default Daily check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCYuU.png)
- if I tick the weekly option, the daily should auto-un-check
  [When Check Weekly, Daily uncheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgpdS.png)

I am not sure how to proceed...

I have grabbed the code from chrome and it is the following:

daily newsletter code:

```
<div class="um-field um-field-b um-field-mailchimp" data-key="um_mailchimp_8_7">

    <div class="um-field-area">

        <label class="um-field-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]" value="1">
            <span class="um-field-checkbox-state"><i class="um-icon-android-checkbox-outline-blank"></i></span>
            <span class="um-field-checkbox-option">Daily Newsletter Registration - MailChimp</span>
        </label>

        <div class="um-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the code for weekly newsletter

```
<div class="um-field um-field-b um-field-mailchimp" data-key="um_mailchimp_8_8">
    <div class="um-field-area">
        <label class="um-field-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="um-mailchimp[4c01dced4a]" value="1">
            <span class="um-field-checkbox-state"><i class="um-icon-android-checkbox-outline-blank"></i></span>
            <span class="um-field-checkbox-option">Weekly Newsletter Registration - MailChimp</span>
        </label>
        <div class="um-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if I should use javascript, jquery or something completely different...

Many thanks all

Regards

Ivan

Comment: You should probably not force opt-in. This goes against something that mail chimp is forcing intentionally.

Comment: You can run a jquery code like: jQuery('input[name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]"]').prop('checked', true); inside your register template to make it selected by default.

Comment: Thanks Bruno,

the problem I have is I am not so technical and therefore I dont know how t add the code... is there something I can do with the interface? or I need to go in the serverside?

Comment: Anyone can help?